# Project File (rptproj) is in a strange structure for SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I received an SSRS project from a colleague that I cannot open.  This was created with SSDT 2015 and I am trying to open it with the same.  The error I get when trying to open it is:

> (project Name).rptproj : error  : There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

The .rptproj file is in this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <FullPath>Debug</FullPath>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <Platform></Platform>
    <TargetReportFolder></TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder></TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder></TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder></TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL></TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <State></State>
    <DataSources>@(DataSource)</DataSources>
    <DataSets>@(DataSet)</DataSets>
    <Reports>@(Report)</Reports>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DataSet Include="(data source file name).rsd" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Report Include="(Report Name).rdl" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

I looked at an SSRS project that I *can* open and it looks completely different:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ToolsVersion="2.0">
  <State></State>
  <DataSources>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>(data source name).rds</Name>
      <FullPath>(data source name).rds</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>(dataset name).rsd</Name>
      <FullPath>(dataset name).rsd</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
  </DataSets>
  <Reports>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>(report name).rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>(report name).rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
...
```

I'm looking to understand why these differences exist and how I can get the project opened in visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue - using the Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 on 2 different computers. After comparing the version of the SQL Server Reporting Services, I noticed that they were different (one was using the v13.0 and another with the v14.0).

So the first step was to install the same version of the **SQL Server Data Tools** (v14.0.61712.50). After that I've deleted the file with the "*.rptproj.rsuser*" extension which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ToolsVersion` attribute on the `Project` node. I've found that the version of SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 is not able to open the higher versions. SSDT for VS2017 seems to only operate on the new versions and will upgrade existing report projects.

If your colleague upgraded the project, there might still be a backup in the folder. If they created it from scratch in 2017, the only way of going back is to create a new 2015 report project with the `.rdl` and other files (which should be backward-compatible).

Solutions, I've seen, can be passed back and forth without issue. So things like solution folders will, at least, be preserved.

Comment: We are both using 2015.  My version of the project file listed second above does not have a `ToolsVersion` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the SSDTSetup.exe. There was an update that allowed msbuild to be able to build rptproj files. Your xml above looks ok.

Look in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild

Do you see a folder called Reporting Services (contains 10 .dlls for building the rptproj)

If not, go here...
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/09/25/msbuild-support-for-reporting-services-projects-now-available/

Look for:
•Download SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015
•Download Reporting Services Projects for Visual Studio 2017

I'm using 2015
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Scroll down to...
SSDT for VS 2015 (standalone installer)
download Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 (17.4)

After you install the SSDT, you'll get that Reporting Services folder mentioned above. 
You should be able to build it now. 
You would also need to install this on a build server.